# Disable Ctrl+TAB navigation for TabControl in WPF

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, tabcontrol

I need to disable the ctrl + tab navigation in my TabControl of my WPF application.

I tried overriding with

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && e.Key == Key.Tab)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

but this isn't working

Comment: Did you try overriding `OnPreviewKeyDown` instead?